# Navigation menu alignment and active state issue

Tags: html, css

I have two questions:

1. How do I align the text to the middle of the box with bg color aqua without removing height: 100% as I want the border bottom on active state to touch the ul's entire height? `vertical-align: middle` doesn't seem to be working.
2. How do I make sure that the border-bottom stays highlighted when clicked on the link?

```css
ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
}

ul.nav .nav-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

ul.nav .nav-item:active, ul.nav .nav-item:focus {
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  outline: none;
}

ul.nav .nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav .nav-link:hover, ul.nav .nav-link:focus, ul.nav .nav-link:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Account</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: table` on your `li` (`nav-item`) elements and `display: table-cell` for the anchor elements within. Please see below snippet.

This will allow you to use `vertical-align` more effectively.

```css
ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
}

ul.nav .nav-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: table;
}

ul.nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:active, ul.nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  outline: none;
}

ul.nav .nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.nav .nav-link:hover, ul.nav .nav-link:focus, ul.nav .nav-link:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Account</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it doesn't address the 2nd question though.

Comment: @takeradi Ah, didn't see that at first - apologies... It's a simple case of adding the anchor element active / focus states to your style (ul.nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:focus) I've edited my answer so it works now.

Comment: i already accepted the answer but i wanted to check with you if there is a way to avoid the jump in the text when the link is selected. thanks again for your answer!

Comment: @takeradi I'lll take a look as soon as I can :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is what you want? `<li>` aren't input elements so they don't have a :focus state.

```css
ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
}

ul.nav .nav-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.nav .nav-item .nav-link{
  display: block;
  line-height: 42px;
}


ul.nav .nav-item .nav-link:active, ul.nav .nav-item .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  outline: none;
}

ul.nav .nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav .nav-link:hover, ul.nav .nav-link:focus, ul.nav .nav-link:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Account</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is there an alternative to line-height. why cant i use vertical-align: middle

Comment: Vertical-align will only work if you have multiple elements inside a single parent. In your case the <a> tags are single child so they have nothing to align with.